# Create a web annotation tool

Tags: javascript, html, web, label

**I am trying to code a program in which when i select a text inside an iframe on mouse up i want to highlight it and give it a label. after that save it in json format** 
I want to make an annotation tool as part of my project. I load a web page in a frame and after that i want to select text from mouse and then tag highlighted text from the available set of options from a drop down menu. I am new to web so i need help to get started with annotation tool. I know there are plenty available online but I want to make my own tool as part of a bigger project.
so the question is: How do I implement this functionality in my html web page where I highlight the text using mouse and then give a highlighted text some label or tag ?

Comment: Ok, and what is your concrete question/problem?

Comment: so the question is: How do I implement this functionality in my html web page where I highlight the text using mouse and then give a highlighted text some label or tag ?

Comment: this  kind of tool are extension tool for browser, like chrome

Comment: I have not implemented it yet. I know that there are online tools and extensions available. but i want to make the tool myself

Comment: I am trying to code a program in which when i select a text inside an iframe on mouse up i want to highlight it and give it a label. after that save it in json format

Comment: @irumzahra, I didn't say that, you have to learn yourself how to create extension tool for browser --your next answer should be put in an another question, and you have to show the code you made

Comment: Oh thanks so much for great help ! I didn't know learning myself was an option :) 
Sometimes people are in hurry and are not web developers but doing stuff for some other reasons under a deadline :)

Comment: Have you figured it out?